# jQuery Json order list by hightest number in json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am reading some json data and listing it on my page.

One of the values in the json data is score ... "val.score"

This tells me the score of the username.

I've also added a count variable.

What I need to do it to order the list starting with the hightest user score.

Here is my current code:

```
var count = 1;
$.each(jsonData.listing, function(key, val) {

   $("#output").append('<li>Rank'+count+' username'+val.username+'score'+val.score+'</li>');

   count++;
});
```

Comment: You could push them in an array. score becomes your index, then you move  through this array in a for-in-loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sort`:

```
var count = 1;
var listing = jsonData.listing.sort(function (a, b) { return b.score - a.score; });
$.each(listing, function(key, val) {

  $("#output").append('<li>Rank'+count+' username'+val.username+'score'+val.score+'</li>');
  count++;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply sort your listing before you go through it ($.each):

```
jsonData.listing.sort(function(x,y){
    if(x.score === y.score) return 0;
    return x.score < y.score ? 1 : -1;
});
```